# Device to analyse serving with topspin in tennis from the side?

Tags: tennis, technology, spin

My friend Timo mentioned that GoPro Hero 3 can connect to your phone with some lag. This opens me an opportunity to get immediate feedback about my tennis serving with topspin. I want to train serving with topspin and I would like to see how the shot looks from the side. Basically, attach the camera to the net and look the shot with your phone/monitor (probably in the future in Google glasses or something like that). Little lag does not matter here, it just need to be fast enough not to be irritating. I currently use the iPhone 5 camera for the analysis but hard to see the ball's path and very slow method.

[image]

**Is there any device to help in analysing serving with topspin from the side?**

Comment: I am testing with a better camera [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128201/aperture-showing-videos-with-odd-lines-how-to-see-videos-nicely-in-osx) and I need to learn to show it nicely, not sure whether some program to help with import.

Answer (score 1):

**Comparison to professional sport technology**

In professional sport technology, there are systems such as [Hawk-Eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawk-Eye) to approximate the flight path of the ball. According to [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Tennis/How-does-Hawk-Eye-work-in-professional-tennis-matches), it has `"Six high performance cameras (up to 1000fps)"`. In golf, there are devices that track the features of the ball such as spin, angle and velocity.

I don't know any low-budget device that you could use for your own training. I am testing different state of art solutions such as [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128523/custom-slowness-speed-in-final-cut-pro-video) and I feel I am reinventing the wheel, there must be some easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the babolat play racket line which can measure levels of spin achieved with specific shots.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of a new device called playsight, but I've never seen it in action.

http://www.playsight.com/whatisplaysight

http://www.playsight.com

They have it installed in some clubs. It does look pretty amazing.